# inotifywait not performing the while loop in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh, alpine-linux, inotify

I want to put a file watcher on a directory in my Docker container. I'm using `entrypoint.sh` script to setup the script that places a file watcher. The setup is like so:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Trigger the script with the file watcher in the background
./bin/watcher.sh &
```

And the `watcher.sh` script contains the `inotifywait` command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait \
    --event create --event delete \
    --event modify --event move \
    --format "%e %w%f" \
    --monitor --outfile '/var/log/inotifywait.log' \
    --syslog --quiet --recursive \
    /etc/haproxy |
while read CHANGED;
do
    echo "$CHANGED"
    haproxy -W -db -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid) &
done
```

However, although the watcher is listed when i check with `top`, and it reports changes in the defined log file, the loop never triggers. I've tried debugging the loop with simple:

```sh
    touch /var/log/special.log
    echo "${CHANGED}" >> /var/log/special.log
```

But file never gets created, and nothing gets echoed in it. What is the right way to use `inotifywait` with loop in bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are explicitly sending output to a file rather than `stdout` using the `--outfile` option. Nothing is ever written to `stdout`, so the `read` statement in your `while` loop never reads any data.

You probably want:

```
inotifywait \
    --event create --event delete \
    --event modify --event move \
    --format "%e %w%f" \
    --monitor \
    --syslog --quiet --recursive \
    /etc/haproxy |
while read CHANGED;
do
    echo "$CHANGED"
    haproxy -W -db -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid) &
done
```

Comment: Still nothing happens when I remove the `--outfile`. And strangely enough when I removed the outfile, and try to trigger the inotifywait, after first "execution" it just disappears when I list processes with `top`.

Comment: Sorry, it works, my fault, I just commented it out, and sh had some problem with it, but when I delete it, it triggers normally.