# bash -- execute command on file change; doubling issue + how to skip loop until command completes

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, inotify, inotifywait

I'm a `bash` noob, and I am trying to set up a sort of "hot reload" functionality for a project I'm working on using `inotifywait`. Ubuntu 20.04 if that matters.

Here is what I hoped would have worked:

```
inotifywait -m -r ../.. -e modify,create,delete |
    while read line; do
        custom_command
    done
```

#### I'm having two problems:

**Issue #1** is that `custom_command` takes some time to work, and so if I make more changes to the directory in the meantime, `custom command` appears to "queue up" `custom_command`, where really I just want it to keep the most recent one and drop the others.

**Issue #2** is that I'm getting some sort of "double output." So for example if I `bash auto-exec.sh` and `auto-exec.sh` looks like this:

```
inotifywait -m -r . -q -e modify,create,delete
```

Then each time a change registers, I get this as output (not a mistake that it's doubled -- I get two identical lines each time there is a modification):

```
./ MODIFY auto-exec-testfile.txt
./ MODIFY auto-exec-testfile.txt
```

I should note I've tried making changes both with Visual Code Studio and gedit, with the same results.

If I modify the `bash` file like so:

```
inotifywait -m -r . -q -e modify,create,delete |
    while read line; do
        echo "$line"
        echo "..."
    done
```

I get the following output each time there is a change:

```
./ MODIFY auto-exec-testfile.txt
...
./ MODIFY auto-exec-testfile.txt
...
```

If I modify `bash_test.sh` to the following:

```
inotifywait -m -r . -q -e modify,create,delete |
    while read line; do
        echo "help me..."
    done
```

Then I get the following each time a change is made:

```
help me...
help me...
```

**What happened to the the `./ MODIFY ...` line??** Presumably there's something I don't understand about bash, `stdout` or similar /related concepts here?

And finally, if I change the `.sh` file to the following:

```
inotifywait -m -r . -q -q -e modify,create,delete |
    while read _; do
        echo "help me..."
    done
```

Then I get no output at all. This one I think I understand, because the `-q -q` means that `inotifywait` is in ["super silent" mode](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), so there is no log and therefore nothing to trigger the `while`.

What I'd love to do is just trigger the code *once* when something changes, and drop all but the most recent execution. I'm not sure doing this using a `while` is entirely necessary, but I tried `inotifywait -m -r . -q -q -e modify,create,delete | echo "help me.."`, and the script printed "help me..." once at startup, then exited on modification.

Assistance very much appreciated.

**EDIT - 20201-Mar-23**
I removed `-m` and `create` from the `inotifywait` line, and it appears to work as expected, except that it doesn't stay "up" in monitor mode. So this at least only gives me one entry from `inotifywait`:

```
notifywait -r .. -q -e modify,delete |
    while read line1; do
        echo ${line1}
    done
```

Related:

1. [inotifywait - pause monitoring while executing command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083271/inotifywait-pause-monitoring-while-executing-command)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140679/using-inotify-to-monitor-a-directory-but-not-working-100
3. [inotifywait not performing the while loop in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813061/inotifywait-not-performing-the-while-loop-in-bash-script)

Comment: You could add `--format '%e %f'` to the inotify options to see which event is noted.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want. If you just want 1 event, don't use `-m`.

Comment: The multiple lines are probably caused by multiply inotify processes running. Maybe doing a `killall inotifywait` before each new attempt to get this working resolves that (or put it in the script as the first thing to do).

Comment: Indeed, when inotifywait is called with `-q`, you get no output from that, and as a consequence the `read` will never be fed anything, and hence will never return, and your script is just seemingly sitting there, doing *apparently* nothing.

Comment: Make that `-qq` in my last comment.

Comment: @Roadowl I only want one event per modification. Currently I get 2 events every time a file is modified. No luck with `killall`.

Answer (score -1):

```
while inotifywait -e close_write,delete .; do 
    pkill custom_command
    custom_command&
done
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. Please add context and explanation to all your answers to make them useful to other users.